# How do I export from SQL Server to Excel, and column headers with the corresponded comments?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, export

I have a table `Buildings` in SQL Server and I want to export it to Excel, but change the headers to a comment added. I define the table like this:

[image: Table Devices]

and I know the comment is stored in a view `sys.extended_properties` from which I can select it.

I have tried to export the table, but it header is in English, what I want is change it to Chinese and get an Excel file like this:

[image: Exported File format]

Comment: You will have to do this by writing a query. You can't use the export data function from SSMS for this.

Comment: DBA tools allows such things